# React.js - TypeError: college.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the college array but it is throwing an error saying "college .map is not a function". I want to loop over the array. But when I checked the type of college it is saying that type of(college) is an object. I have declared the college state as array. I am not getting how can I loop over the college array to display the information. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
    import React, { useState, useContext,useEffect } from 'react'
    import {
     Form,
     FormGroup,
     Label,
    Input,
    Button,
    Col
     } from 'reactstrap'
    import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'
    import axios from 'axios'
    const AddUser = () => {
    const { addUser } = useContext(GlobalContext)
    const history = useHistory()
    const [fullname, setFullName] = useState('')
    const [birthdate,setBirthDate]=useState()
    const [address,setAddress]=useState('')
    const [gender,setGender]=useState('')
    const [college,setCollege]=useState([])
    const handleSubmit = () => {
    const newUser = {
   id: uuid(),
   fullname,
   birthdate,
   address,
   college,
   gender
  }
  addUser(newUser)
  history.push('/userslist')
 }

 useEffect(() => {
 async function fetchData(name){
  const response = await axios.get(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search`,{
      params:{name}
    }
  )
  console.log(response.data)
  
 setCollege({ college: response.data })   
   }
 fetchData('Middle')
 }, [])

 return (
 <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>Name</Label>
    <Input type='text' placeholder='Enter Name'
      value={fullname}
      onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
      name='fullname'
    />
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup>
    <Label>BirthDate</Label>
    <Input type='date'
      placeholder='Enter BirthDate'
      value={birthdate} onChange={(e)=>setBirthDate(e.target.value)}
      name='birthdate'
    />
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup>
      <Label>Address</Label>
      <Input type='textarea'
        placeholder='Enter Address'
        value={address} onChange={(e)=>setAddress(e.target.value)}
        name='address' />
    </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup row>
    <Label for="exampleSelect" sm={2}>Select College Name</Label>
    <Col sm={10}>
      <Input type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect" onChange={(e)=>e.target.value}>
      <option value='' disabled hidden>College List</option>
      {college ?
        college.map((col, index) => {
          return <option value={col.name} key={index + 1}>{col.name}</option>
        }):null
      }
      </Input>
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
    <FormGroup tag="fieldset">
      <Label>Please Select Gender</Label>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>
          <Input type='radio' name='gender'
            onChange={(e)=>setGender(e.target.value)}
            value='Male'
            checked={gender === "Male"}
          />
        Male
      </Label>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label >
          <Input type='radio' name='gender'
            onChange={(e)=>setGender(e.target.value)}
            value='Female'
            checked={gender === "Female"} />
        Female
      </Label>
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>
          <Input type='radio' name='gender'
            onChange={(e)=>setGender(e.target.value)}
            value='Other'
            checked={gender === 'Other'} />
      Other
      </Label>
      </FormGroup>

    </FormGroup>
    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
   </Form>
   )
 }

 export default AddUser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your line:  `setCollege({ college: response.data })`   will replace the default array you set in state. Setters for useStates always replaces the entire state.

do `setCollege([...college, {college: response.data}])` instead and it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You are setting college as an object here

```
 setCollege({ college: response.data })
```

Change that to

```
 setCollege([{ college: response.data }])
```

Or append like

```
 setCollege([...college, { college: response.data }])
```

and that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly placing the response object in your `college` state. `.map()` is function of array, so response from your API might not be in array format. Convert it into array then you can loop through array with `map()`.